# Micro-Cap 12 error message prevents simulating a variable capacitor

Tags: simulation

Micro-Cap 12 won't let me put a conditional statement in its capacitance parameter to vary its capacitance per conditions. I'm using this capacitor as a throttle which I name: 'tcap' ...

```
.define tcap {100f + STOP}

.define STOP if(I(IndLoad) > 300, 30p, 0)
```

The intention is to raise the capacitance of tcap to 30pF (or, more) if the current of IndLoad should rise to a minimum of 300 amperes. The default capacitance of tcap is 100 femto Farads.

What do I do?

Comment: How do you expect to realize this in a real circuit? Perhaps your simulation should model that more literally. Two capacitors and a switch?

Comment: @DaveTweed Good idea. Thanks. I was thinking of a variable capacitor, but maybe that's not practical, nor doable, per these requirements?